How to map await api data in nextjs server component
Having an issue where the map is not displaying my items after an api call.
export default async function LoginPage() {
  const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/machines");

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch machine data");
  }

  const machines = await res.json();

  console.log(machines.data);

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Login Page</h1>
      <p>Testing...</p>
      {machines.data.map((machine: any) => {
        <p>{machine.name}</p>;
      })}
    </main>
  );
}


it displays everything up to Testing... and doesn't include the machine data map.
I tried outputting the machine data in the map and was expecting it to display on screen.

you have synatx error and please learn map() you need to return something

In this case, the map() function doesn't output any JSX because it doesn't return anything within its block. A correct approach would be to use a return statement like this:
return (
  <main>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
    <p>Testing...</p>
    {machines.data.map((machine: any) => {
      return <p>{machine.name}</p>;
    })}
  </main>
);

Alternatively, if you don't want to use curly braces {} with an explicit return, you can use parentheses () to achieve the same result in a more concise way:
return (
  <main>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
    <p>Testing...</p>
    {machines.data.map((machine: any) => (
      <p>{machine.name}</p>
    ))}
  </main>
);

